# How to pass error code from userdata to code pipeline to indicate the failure

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-codepipeline

I have a requirement where I will download a jar from s3 with different version to the ec2 instance. I will do this as part of userdata section. It works fine.
Suppose if the jar is not available then the application doesn't start. I have a check in place for this and return non 0 ( i.e exit 1 ).
In cloud-init-output.log, I can see the error message and its getting exit with non 0 value. But, in the pipeline stage it is showing success.
Below is the sample code:

```
echo "Post deployment checks"

if [ `netstat -ntpl | grep java | grep 8080 | wc -l` -eq 0 ]
    then
        echo "Application doesn't listen 8080 port"
        echo "Deployment is unsuccessful!"
        exit 1
    else
        echo "Application listens 8080 port"
fi
```

My question is, How can I pass value back to the pipeline, so that the processing halts at the stage if the app is not started.

Comment: Which action in the pipeline initiates this?

Comment: Action type is Deploy

Comment: - Name: CreateEC2Stack
             InputArtifacts:
               - Name: SourceOutput
             ActionTypeId:
               Category: Deploy
               Owner: AWS
               Provider: CloudFormation
               Version: 1
             Configuration: 
               ActionMode: REPLACE_ON_FAILURE
               StackName: !Sub scs-${EnvironmentName}-${Region}-${PipelineType}-hds-ec2
               RoleArn: !Ref CodePipelineExecutionRoleArn
               Capabilities: CAPABILITY_NAMED_IAM
               TemplatePath: SourceOutput::ec2-route53.yaml

Answer (score 2):

In your CloudFormation template it's possible to wait until receiving a signal before completing. If this signal isn't received within the timeout window, it'll ROLLBACK the template and your deploy should fail. There are a few ways to do this. Here's some documentation options.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-signal.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-cfn-waitcondition.html

I'd prefer the first option, just add a `CreationPolicy` on the EC2 Instance and then signal it in `UserData`. Like So:

```
Resources:
  AppEC2Instance:
    Type: "AWS::EC2::Instance"
    CreationPolicy:
      ResourceSignal:
        Timeout: "PT5M"
    Properties:
      UserData:
        Fn::Base64:
          Fn::Join:
            - ""
            - - "#!/bin/bash -x\n"
              - "aws s3 sync s3://mybucket-id/ ./\n"
              - "java -jar ./app.jar\n"
              - "/opt/aws/bin/cfn-signal -e $? --stack ",
              - !Ref AWS::StackName
              - " --resource AppEC2Instance --region "
              - !Ref AWS::Region
              - "\n"
```

Using `-e $?` should provide the exit code back to the stack and, I would hope, would then push it back to the pipeline.

Answer (score -1):

I can think of three high level options to get the failure back to the pipeline:

1. Figure out how to fail the CloudFormation stack update when cloud-init fails.
2. Add a subsequent action to the pipeline (e.g. Lambda Invoke) where you write some code to fail the action if cloud-init fails.
3. Use something like CodeDeploy to manage deployments to EC2 instances.